# ¿Cómo subir una imagen a servidor desde Android?

Tags: java, php, android

Espero y me puedan ayudar con este problema, bueno pues he intentando subir una imagen a mi servidor local (guardar la imagen en una carpeta en especifico) desde una aplicación de android utilizando web service con php, pero no lo he conseguido, he estado buscando información acerca de ello, pero lamentablemente no me ha funcionado ningún método, encontré uno que todo va bien hasta el momento de subir la imagen porque la imagen no se guarda en ningún lado del servidor. Para realizar la conexión desde android con php he utilizado la librería "com.loopj.android:android-async-http" espero y me puedan ayudar en este pequeño problema les dejo mi código 
MainActivity:

```
private Button tomarFoto;
private Button subirFoto;
private ImageView verFoto;
private  static final int TAKE_PICTURE=1;

double aleatorio = new Double(Math.random() * 100).intValue();
String foto = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/imagen/"+ aleatorio +".jpg";
File imagen;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tomarFoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toarFoto);
    subirFoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subirFoto);
   // verFoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagen);
    tomarFoto.setOnClickListener(this);
    subirFoto.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    v.getId();
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.subirFoto:
            subirFoto();
            break;
        case R.id.toarFoto:
            tomarFoto();
            break;
    }
}
private void  subirFoto(){
    AsyncHttpClient  client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    String url = "http://192.168.0.103:8080/android/foto/subirfoto.php";
    RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();
    try {
        requestParams.put("imagen",imagen.getAbsolutePath());
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this,e.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    RequestHandle post = client.post(url, requestParams, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            if (statusCode == 200){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Se ha subido la imagen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error al subir la imagen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
private void tomarFoto(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    Uri output = Uri.fromFile(new File(foto));
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, output);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}

@Override
public  void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    verFoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagen);
    verFoto.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(foto));
    imagen = new File(foto);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),imagen.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Código de mi PHP

```
<?php  

$image=$_FILES["imagen"]["name"];
$ruta=$_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"];
$destino="img/".$image;
copy($ruta,$destino);

?>
```

Espero su ayuda! de antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Has intentado esto?

```
requestParams.put("imagen",imagen);
```

en php prueba esto:

```
$file_path = "/uploads/";
$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['imagen']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
    echo "success";
} else{
    echo "fail";
}
```

Como ejemplo te dejo esto:

```
public static void postImage(String ImageLink){
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
try {
    params.put("imagen", new File(ImageLink));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.post("http://192.168.0.103:8080/android/foto/subirfoto.php", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
        System.out.println("statusCode "+statusCode);//statusCode 200
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

    }
});
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Mario! me ha funcionado muy bien,
en android 5.1 subió sin problemas, en en android 6 tuve que agregar los nuevos permisos, pero ha funcionado, una vez más Gracias!